# How to load data from other URL in MODAL content

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

How to load data from other url inside modal content.
 URL: host/faqs.html

Load into modal of host/registrations

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap modals, as seen in: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Once you did it, jut do something like that using `<iframe>` tag:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <iframe src="host/faqs.html"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some backend frameworks offers you ways to do it properly.